# FetchXMLBuilder is Missing in Plugins section of XRMToolBox

Tags: dynamics-crm, xrmtoolbox

When i open "*XRMToolBox for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 365*" i am not able to find "**FetchXMLBuilder**" in Plugins section. but i have "**FetchXMLTester**", please help me to get a "FetchXMLBuilder".

[UI where i am searching for FetchXMLBuilder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBQvz.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install it first. To do it do following steps:

1. Click Tools -> Plugins Store
2. In appeared window look for "Fetch Xml Builder" and check it.
3. Click "Install" button.

If you done everything the right way it should appear in the initial list of plugins.

Comment: Thank you for guidance. It worked. but i was getting exception when i tried to install, later i cleaned cache in XRMToolBox Plugins Store. It worked..!!

Answer (score 2):

Step's suggested by ***Andrill Butenko*** worked **fine for me**.
But i faced a **Exception Error** while installing "FetchXMLBuilder",
I resolved the Installation error by following way :

1. In "*XRMToolBox Plugin Store*" Window at right top after "*proxy setting*" you have **Clean XRMToolBox Plugin Store**. By clicking that i cleaned the cache.

This  step resolved my problem. 
[Screenshot of Clearing the cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udNce.jpg)